# single adjective capturing "unnecessary" and with the connotation of "dangerous"/"destructive"?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Unnecessary" can refer to something that is unnecessary but harmless, or unnecessary and costly, but not inherently harmful.

I am looking for a word to describe a situation where there is a government or organization that has hired a person who does not actually add anything to the service intended to being provided (unnecessary) but simultaneously undermines the organization in the service of his own objectives (dangerous/destructive).

For example, a bureaucrat that doesn't do anything of value (could be fired without any needs of the organization being endangered), but uses his bureaucratic power to achieve his own political/financial ends while risking the organization he works for.

**I'd really like a *single adjective* that describes this idea that someone/something is not only unnecessary but also dangerous.**

Comment: something harmful is always unnecessary.

Comment: How would you use the adjective in a sentence?

Comment: *Deleterious* is as close as I can come.

Comment: @ubi hatt, no that's not true. Something can be a necessary evil

Comment: I think there ain't no such critter… "worse than useless" might work but that's not a single adjective.

Comment: Counterproductive?